# When a solution is diluted, the number of moles of the solute decreases. what would happen to the molarity?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

When a solution is diluted, the number of moles of the solute decreases, so the molarity decreases??

Comment: moles = molarity X volume

Comment: Nunber of moles is still the same but the volume of the solution increases

Answer (score 1):

The number of moles of solute does not decrease on dilution.
For example suppose you add 2 moles of NaOH to 100cm3.
Now if you dilute this solution to 1000cm3 you  are still going to have 2 moles of NaOH.
But now the total volume has changed ,hence the concentration also changes.